# How do I fetch filesystem.squashfs to an UEFI pxe server?

Tags: uefi, pxe

I've tried to build UEFI PXE server, my grub.cfg setting as below:

```
menuentry 'install' {
linux /ubuntu-installer/arm64/linux ip=dhcp 
initrd /ubuntu-installer/arm64/initrd.gz live-installer/net-image=http://192.168.100.1/ubuntu16/install/filesystem.squashfs
```

When I try to boot via pxe, it will show error:"file not found", but if I removed  live-installer/net-image=http://192.168.100.1/ubuntu16/install/filesystem.squashfs from grub.cfg, then I can success boot into grub menu.
However, when I try to install, it fails at the step "Install the System".
I am sure that my filesystem.squashfs file path is correct, just don't know how to fetch it.
Does someone know how to fetch filesystem.squashfs it on an UEFI PXE server? 
Sorry for my English.